# Error during execusion of While loop on Firebird-SQL Script

Tags: sql, loops, while-loop, firebird

I have tried to execute the following script:

```
SET TERM !! ;
EXECUTE BLOCK AS

DECLARE I INTEGER;

BEGIN

  I = 296;

  WHILE (I < 500) DO
  BEGIN

   UPDATE DD_TABLE SET DATA_FLOW = DATA_RAW
   WHERE DATA_COUNTER = I 
   I = I + 1;
  END

END!!
SET TERM;!!
```

and I got the error:

```
 Engine Code    : 335544569
Engine Message :
Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 15, column 4
```

I'm not sure exactly what I missed.

Comment: what is your DMBS?

Comment: @Amirhossein As indicated by the presence of the firebird tag, the OP is using Firebird.

Comment: You error message is incomplete, the error message is missing the unknown token, `I`. This is caused by a missing semi-colon to terminate the update statement before you do `I = I + 1` (so use `WHERE DATA_COUNTER = I;`, note the `;`). Voting to close as a typo. Be aware that you can do this more easily (and probably quicker) without a loop by using `UPDATE DD_TABLE SET DATA_FLOW = DATA_RAW WHERE DATA_COUNTER between 296 and 499`

Comment: the script you sent worked perfectely any thanks. but the correction to my script(adding ;) where I want to test the while loop did not work and gave me the folowing error:
Message: isc_dsql_prepare failed
SQL Message : -206 can't format message 13:794 -- message file C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\firebird.msg not found
Engine Code : 335544569 Engine Message : Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -206 Column unknown PROCEDURECOUNT At line 14, column 25